# Why is no code being executed after this switch statement?

Tags: c++, switch-statement

For some reason nothing is being executed after `tulip.flowerHealth()` in the main(). Did I do something wrong with the switch case or am I creating the object incorrectly?

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "flower.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    flower tulip;
    int i = 1;
    cout << "Press 1 to water. Press 2 to do nothing." << endl;

    while( tulip.curWater() > 0 && tulip.curWater() < 6 ){
        cin >> i;
        if ( i == 1){
            tulip.water();
        } else {
            tulip.dry();
        }
        cout << "Flower water level is: " << tulip.curWater() << " " << tulip.flowerHealth() << endl;
    } // end of while loop

    cout << "Your flower has died. :(" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

flower.h

```
#ifndef FIRSTPROJ_FLOWER_H
#define FIRSTPROJ_FLOWER_H

#include <string>

using namespace std;

class flower
{
public:
    string flowerHealth();
    int curWater();
    void water();
    void dry();
    int waterLvl = 1;
};

#endif //FIRSTPROJ_FLOWER_H
```

flower.cpp

```
#include "flower.h"

int flower::curWater(){
    return waterLvl;
}

void flower::water(){
    waterLvl++;
};

void flower::dry() {
    waterLvl--;
};

string flower::flowerHealth(){
    switch(curWater()){
        case 1 : return "Flower desperately needs water!";
        case 2 : return "Flower is doing alright.";
        case 3 : return "Optimal water for the flower to grow.";
        case 4 : return "Flower is doing alright.";
        case 5 : return "Flower is being over watered!";
    }
}
```

Comment: Educated guess: `curWater()` returns a value other than a number 1 through 5. `flowerHealth()` then reaches the closing brace without encountering a `return` statement, which is undefined behavior for a function declared to return something other than `void`.

Comment: The return value of `flowerHealth()` is undefined if `curWater()` does not return a value between 1..5 inclusive. Imagine what would happen if the `main()` loop sees `curWater()` is 1 and calls `dry()`, or sees `curWater()` is 5 and calls `water()`- undefined behavior when `flowerHealth()` is called!

Comment: You sure it’s not just waiting on your input? You take input at the start of the loop but only prompt outside of it.

Comment: The program works correctly for me if you start with `2`, and don't go past the bounds. If you start with `1` it segfaults.  It's not clear why you prompt for "1 to water, 2 to do nothing", but then for input 1 you call `dry()` and for input 2 you call `water()`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Perfect, thank you. You are exactly right that I was going outside of the scope of the switch case.

Comment: @M.M it was just an error I put in while trying to debug the program. My apologies.